# Com+ constructor deleted

Tags: .net, com+

I have a .Net object in a com+ application. The problem is that whenever I compile my .net object, it's constructor gets deleted.
Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it deleted from the code file? Is the constructor declared in a auto generated file?

Comment: No. the code doesn't contain the constructor.